# How to replace tf.placeholder in eager execution

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow2.0

I am using a tf1 code as a reference for developing a model. In the reference code, they used tf.placeholder to give input to the model and the code is

```
class model(object):
    def __init__(self, lstm_size, batch_len, output_nodes, keep_prob, learning_rate=0.001):
        self.inputs_ = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[batch_len, None, 512], name='lstm_inputs')
        self.targets_ = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.int32, [batch_len], name='lstm_targets')
```

The execution mode of this model is Graph Execution(tf.Graph).

Since I want to convert and run the code in eager execution. But, the tf.placeholder will not work in eager execution. How can I replace the tf.placeholder without affecting the input name , dtype, and shape of the input value for sake of eager execution.!

Again I need it to convert for eager execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tf.keras.Input()` in the place of [tf.compat.v1.placeholder()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/placeholder) to run the code in eager execution mode.

Also, please check this [migration guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate) to convert `TensorFlow 1.x` code to `TensorFlow 2.x`.